# Do the Federal or California WARN acts apply to the situation at Twitter?

Tags: united-states, california, employment

There have been mentions in the news regarding both Federal and state laws requiring a 60 day notice for “mass terminations” might apply to actions at Twitter.

It has been [widely reported](https://arstechnica.com/tech-policy/2022/11/twitter-shuts-offices-for-day-as-it-cuts-50-of-workforce-staff-already-suing/amp/) that 50% of the approximately 7,500 person workforce was recently terminated with a general warning it would happen a few days earlier.

I have seen the trigger for the requirement quoted as 33% and as 50%. Apparently there are many exceptions in the law. Some summaries mention plant closing but it is not clear to me if the law does or doesn’t apply to a location that stays open with a significantly reduced workforce.

Comment: I would assume not all 7500 employees of twitter are employed in California, so other laws might apply, too. For instance, most European countries have much longer notice periods than the US. While you can also lay people off while still paying, that could get expensive, even for twitter.

Comment: The last I heard involved a 3 month severance.   Does being paid for 3 months and told not to show up to work count as 3 months notice?